# How to limit a IP address range using FILTER_VALIDATE_IP

Tags: php, html

I need to implement an IP address filtering system so only authorised IP addresses can access certain resources. I currently use FILTER_VALIDATE_IP and filter_var to validate the IP address.

The problem I am facing is that start and end ip can be 1.1.1.1.1 and the 99.99.99.99 which obviously defeats the who reason for the filtering system. What I need is for the starting IP address for example to be 1.1.1.1.1 but then only the last digit for the ending IP address can be changed e.g 1.1.1.9 otherwise it cannot be saved.

I have included some of the code below:

```
if($_POST["lastip"]=='unavailable'  || $_POST['lastip']==''  || filter_var($_POST['lastip'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) {
if($_POST["startip"]=='unavailable' || $_POST['startip']=='' || filter_var($_POST['startip'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)){

        $this->db->update("user", array("startip" => "?"), array("id" =>$user->id ), array($_POST['startip']));

        Main::redirect("user/tools", array("success", "Your authorisation settings have been updated successfully."));
    }else{
  Main::redirect("user/tools", array("danger", "The starting authorised IP address is not valid. Please try again."));
    }
}else{
Main::redirect("user/tools", array("danger", "The ending authorised IP address is not valid. Please try again."));
```

Comment: Parse the Ip address into 4 parts and create a limit on the last one

Answer (score 0):

code:

```
<?php

function inIpRagne($ip, $ipLowerRange, $ipUpperRange) {
    $pattern = '/(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)/';

    preg_match($pattern, $ip, $ipArr);
    preg_match($pattern, $ipLowerRange, $ipLowerRangeArr);
    preg_match($pattern, $ipUpperRange, $ipUpperRangeArr);

    array_shift($ipArr);
    array_shift($ipLowerRangeArr);
    array_shift($ipUpperRangeArr);

    foreach($ipArr as $index => $digit) {
        if($digit < $ipLowerRangeArr[$index] || $digit > $ipUpperRangeArr[$index]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

//ip not in range = false
$ip = '1.2.3.4.5';
$ipLowerRange = '1.1.1.1.1';
$ipUpperRange = '1.1.1.1.1';
$result = inIpRagne($ip, $ipLowerRange, $ipUpperRange);
var_dump($result);

//ip in range = true
$ip = '1.2.3.4.5';
$ipLowerRange = '1.1.1.1.1';
$ipUpperRange = '1.2.3.4.5';
$result = inIpRagne($ip, $ipLowerRange, $ipUpperRange);
var_dump($result);

//ip not in range = false
$ip = '1.1.1.1.10';
$ipLowerRange = '1.1.1.1.1';
$ipUpperRange = '1.1.1.1.9';
$result = inIpRagne($ip, $ipLowerRange, $ipUpperRange);
var_dump($result);

//ip in range = tue
$ip = '1.1.1.1.9';
$ipLowerRange = '1.1.1.1.1';
$ipUpperRange = '1.1.1.1.9';
$result = inIpRagne($ip, $ipLowerRange, $ipUpperRange);
var_dump($result);
```

result:

```
bool(false)
bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(true)
```

how to use:

```
if(inIpRagne($ip, $ipLowerRange, $ipUpperRange)) {
    //ip is allowed - do your stuff

} else {
    //ip is not allowed
}
```